# Good practic, where the logic must to be? MVC (business layer)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with MVC
as you see I am starting with this..

I have build  a simple sale module

the next code is for return the partial view of details.

I am not sure if all this code must to be on controller.
where do I put the "logic" then?

I believe the equivalent I need its "business layer" but for mvc.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult getdetail(int productoid, int ventaid, float cantidad, string codigobarras)
{
codigobarras =((string.IsNullOrEmpty(codigobarras))?"":codigobarras.ToLower());
Models.Helper.Ventah vh = new Models.Helper.Ventah();
vh.listadoclientes = db.accounts.ToList();
vh.listadoproductos = db.products.ToList();
vh.venta = db.sales.Where(x => x.id == ventaid).FirstOrDefault();
if (productoid == 0)
{ 
//si es 0 lo busco por el código de barras
vh.productoseleccionado = vh.listadoproductos.Where(x => x.code.ToLower().Equals(codigobarras)).FirstOrDefault();
}
else {
//busco el producto por el id
vh.productoseleccionado = vh.listadoproductos.Where(x => x.id == productoid).FirstOrDefault();
}

//regreso el partialview si el objecto es null, de lo contrario continuo
//gracias a esto podre mandar un mensaje "producto no encontrado"
if (vh.productoseleccionado == null)
{
vh.mensaje = "No se encontró ningun producto con el código "+codigobarras;
return PartialView(vh);
}
productoid = vh.productoseleccionado.id;
//veo si ya tiene el producto agregado
var detalle=vh.venta.saledetails.Where(x => x.idproduct == productoid).FirstOrDefault();

if (detalle != null)//significa que ya tiene el producto agregado por lo tanto solo lo sumo
{
//valido que, quepa la cantidad que se ingresó
if (vh.productoseleccionado.amount >= cantidad)
{
vh.productoseleccionado.amount = vh.productoseleccionado.amount - cantidad;
detalle.amount += cantidad;
}
}
else//significa que no tiene el producto aún por lo tanto debo agregarlo
{
//valido que, quepa la cantidaqd que se ingresó
if (vh.productoseleccionado.amount >= cantidad)
{
//agrego el detalle
vh.venta.saledetails.Add(
//creo el detalle
detalle = new Models.saledetail()
{
amount = cantidad,
idproduct = vh.productoseleccionado.id,
idsale = vh.venta.id,
inputprice = vh.productoseleccionado.inputprice,
outputprice = vh.productoseleccionado.outputprice,
ivaprice = vh.productoseleccionado.ivaprice,
});
}
}
db.SaveChanges();
return PartialView(vh);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of it both ways skinny controller fat model and fat controller skinny model.  It more likely depends on how you use the model and controller.  Say for instance you have a music app and the model is a Song and a User.  It would make more sense on a Purchase action (in the controller) to make the User Purchase the Song... sort of like `User.Purchase(Song)`.  Whereas something that affects the whole system, say an on/off switch for the server to share music, may have the logic placed in the Controller with a model User being checked if they have permission.

This question is a bit too much about personal/corporate choice, and everyone has their own preferences, but usually just as long as it makes sense in code, it should be OK.  Except logic in the View.... avoid logic in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Something you could consider is a Service-Repository (or just Repository) pattern to work alongside MVC.  The concept here is the Controller instantiates a Service object (a layer for logic to run on data)  with a Repository object (a layer specifically meant to interact with a database).  The biggest boon for doing this is abstraction of logic, especially from a unit testability standpoint.  The Controller is now only in charge of delegating incoming data and preparing the response, the Service handles business logic (where the brunt of testable code will reside) and the Repository only worries about data access.  Below is an example of how that would be laid out, though simplified in complexity of logic:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetDetail(int Id)
{
    // Do any manipulating of the data sent to the controller

    // Instantiate a service for working with Products
    var service = new ProductService(new ProductRepository("connectionString"));

    // The method off the Service intended for this controller action
    var modelForPartialView = service.GetProductDetail(Id);

    // Return your updated model
    return PartialView(modelForPartialView);
}
```

**Service**

```
private ProductRepository _productRepository;

public ProductService(ProductRepository repo)
{
    _productRepository = repo;
}

public Product GetProductDetail (int Id)
{
    Product product = _productRepository.GetProductDetail(Id);

    // Perform any business logic/manipulation on the Product before returning to the Controller

    return product;
}
```

**Repository**

```
    public ProductRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        // Connection instantiation
    }

    public Product GetProductDetail(int Id)
    {
        // Perform data access here
        var data = DoDataAccess();

        // Potentially fill a data object as well
        return FillProductWithData(data);
    }
```

When it comes down to it, separation of interest is key.  How far you feel you need to go to achieve that level of separation is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Controller should contain only application logic but not business logic. Business logic should be encapsulated in your domain models but not scattered to controllers that will lead to code duplication and high maintenance overheads. A service layer can be added to provide a series of functionalities that cannot be accomplished by domain models alone. Persistence layer, i.e. the repository should handle the mapping and persistence of the domain models.

```
//controller
public class ProductController : Controller{
   private CustomerService _customerService;

   public ProductController(CustomerService customerService){
     _customerService = customerService;
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Purchase(Product product){
     Boolean success = _customerService.Purchase(product);

     return success ? RedirectToAction("Success") : RedirectToAction("Failure"); 

   }
}
```

The controller only manages the application logic, i.e. redirecting the customer to corresponding page based on the result of the transaction.

```
//service
public class AppCustomerService : CustomerService{
  private Customer _currentCustomer;
  private UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

  public AppCustomerService(UnitOfWork unitOfWork){
     _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
     _currentCustomer = _unitOfWork.CustomerRepository.Get(
      CustomerSession.Current.Id);
  }

  public Boolean Purchase(Product product){
     if(_currentCustomer.Purchase(product)){
       _unitOfWork.CustomerRepository.Update(_currentCustomer);
       _unitOfWork.Save();
       return true;
     }

     return false;
  }
}
```

The service class aggregates the required facilities, i.e. CustomerSession, Customer and UnitOfWork in order to perform the purchase transaction.

```
//domain model
public class Customer{

  private long _id;
  private Money _accountBalance;
  private List<Product> _products;

  //list of property methods...

  public Boolean Purchase(Product product){

   //example of business logic

   if(_accountBalance < product.Price || product.Quantity == 0){
     return false;
   }

   _products.Add(product);
   return true;      

  }

}
```

Business logic of purchasing product that is specified in the requirements should be implemented in the domain model.